# How to make folder for static files with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example when I write `<script src=files/script.js></script>` in HTML document it dosen't work, but in site folder files exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Browser get 404 error instead of files/script.js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using express you need to assign a folder as the public folder

eg

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Can I do it only with default modules? And I would like to get link on a article with detail description of actions that i need to do (or only detail description without link =) ).

Comment: @user805222 unsure what you're asking but it's definitely a different question. You should flesh out your questions with code samples and just other information as it's hard to know what kind of answer you're looking for. If you're looking for a node.js server tutorial just google it...

Answer (score 0):

**SIMPLEST WAY**

`npm install statik`

```
var statik = require('statik');
statik({
    port: 1337,
    root: '/Users/<yourUserName>/Downloads/DurandalJS/HTMLStarterKit'
});
```

In your browser:
http:// yourLocalhost :1337/index.html